# Accessing static files in ejs file with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

So I have created a small app using node.js and have served my assets folder like so

```
app.use(express.static('assets'));
```

Now in my `.ejs` file I can reference an image easily, e.g.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = '/img/picture.jpg'
```

Now, what I want to do is loop through all the images in that folder and display them on the page.

Something like

```
var images = new Array();
images = { All pictures in the /img directory }

images.forEach(function(image) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = image;
}
```

**So my question is, how do I get the names of all the static images using JS?** Do I instead have to make an AJAX call to the directory to read the file names? Or do this server-side with node.js and pass the images through to the `.ejs` file. Typically, which is better practice (can be a separate question but I thought I would ask)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, how do I get the names of all the static images using JS?

The client knows nothing about what URLs the server will respond to until it makes a request to them.

> Do I instead have to make an AJAX call to the directory to read the file names?

That would be one possible approach.

> Or do this server-side with node.js and pass the images through to the .ejs file.

That would also work

> Typically, which is better practice (can be a separate question but I thought I would ask)?

It depends.

Using Ajax would require a second HTTP request, but the response could be cached.

Doing it when the page loads would reduce the number of requests but on, but the work to get the list would have to be done every time the page loads and would increase the size of that page.

So which is best, using the only measurable metrics, depends on how often an individual is going to reload the page and how often the list changes.